# shell.setLocation(x, y) with respect to parent and not client area

Tags: java, swt

I have a custom swt shell I created from a parent shell.
I need to set location for  the shell relative to its parent composite. However, because I am invoking setLocation(x, y) on a shell, setLocation(x,y) now works relative to the clientArea.
Is there a way to make the shell.setLocation(x,y) work relative to the PARENT composite NOT clientArea? . ie the custom Shell should always remain within its parent composite even when the parent composite is resized/Moved around the screen.

Sample code snippet:

```
 class CustOmShellTest {
    customShell = new Shell(parent.getShell(), SWT.TOOL | SWT.CLOSE);
        customShell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        customShell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
        customShell.setSize(300, 400);
        customShell.setLocation(parent.getBounds().x, parent.getBounds().y );

}

new CustOmShellTest(parentOfThisInstanceComposite);
```

//This is instance is positioned relative to disPlay . I want it to be psoitioned relative //to parentOfThisInstanceComposite

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a snippet where your custom shell is anchored to a component in the primary shell. I called that component "anchor". Replace it with your control.

The magic method here is `Control.toDisplay()`, and to keep the position you have to add resize and move listeners.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    final Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    label.setText("anchor");
    label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true));

    final Shell customShell = new Shell(shell, SWT.TOOL | SWT.CLOSE);
    customShell.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    customShell.setBackgroundMode(SWT.INHERIT_FORCE);
    customShell.setSize(300, 400);
    customShell.setVisible(true);

    final Listener listener = new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            final Rectangle bounds = label.getBounds();
            final Point absoluteLocation = label.toDisplay(bounds.width, bounds.height);
            customShell.setLocation(absoluteLocation);
            if (shell.getMaximized()) {
                display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        handleEvent(null);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    shell.addListener(SWT.Resize, listener);
    shell.addListener(SWT.Deiconify, listener);
    shell.addListener(SWT.Move, listener);
    customShell.addListener(SWT.Move, listener);

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Note that I added the listener also on the custom shell to make sure it never moves. When the parent shell is moved, the custom shell is moved along with it.

Answer (score 0):

Code below gets me the relative position of the actual
parent  of the custom shell. This needed to be done with RESIZE event ie

//parent.toDisplay(parent.getLocation().x ,
//                        parent.getLocation().y)

```
customShell.addListener(SWT.RESIZE, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(final Event event) {

customShell.setLocation(parent.toDisplay(parent.getLocation().x ,
                        parent.getLocation().y));                
        customShell.layout();
                parent.layout();
            }
        });
```

Thanks for your input